# How to delete all tweets of specific twitter account?

Tags: c#, twitter

I have access token,consumer key about account. how can i delete all tweets of that account.Is there any DLL to do this.I am use POST statuses/destroy/:id rest API but for i need id.I just want to delete all tweet.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe take a look at Tweetinvi? Seems like they have some good documentation on how to do so. Link to their Github below.

[Link Directly to Delete Call](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Tweets#delete-a-tweet)

Answer (score 0):

Delete all tweets can take a lot of time if you do it manually. That's why you need to use tools to [delete all tweets](https://www.allurneedhere.com/2021/10/delete-all-tweets.html) at once